# Chrome extension consuming 1gb of ram

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a chrome extension in which whenever a page is loaded I insert an Iframe into the page and set src  to the html file which loads a script which is a React app, But the issue I'm facing is the more tabs I open the extension consumes more ram, When I have even 2-3 tabs open it consumes 500mb of ram.

This is how I'm inserting the iframe into the page.

```
  if (!document.getElementById("app-container")) {
    appIframeContainer = document.createElement("iframe");
    appIframeContainer.allowFullscreen = false;
    appIframeContainer.src = chrome.runtime.getURL("/index.html");
    appIframeContainer.id = "app-container-iframe";
    const appContainer = document.createElement("div");
    appContainer.id = "app-container";
    appContainer.style.display = "none";

    const resizeHandle = document.createElement("div");

    resizeHandle.id = "resize-handle";
    resizeHandle.classList.add("ui-resizable-handle");
    resizeHandle.classList.add("ui-resizable-w");

    resizeHandle.innerHTML =
      '<div class="resize-handle-horizontal-bar"></div><div class="resize-handle- 
       horizontal-bar"></div><div class="resize-handle-horizontal-bar"></div>';

    appContainer.appendChild(resizeHandle);
    document.querySelector("body").appendChild(appContainer);
    appContainer.appendChild(appIframeContainer);
    $("#app-container").resizable({
      handles: { w: "#resize-handle" },
    });
}
```

Comment: sounds like your iframe is consuming a lot of resources

Comment: Do you know any possible reason behind it? @Bravo

Comment: Use devtools to investigate, there are [many articles](https://www.google.com/search?q=devtools+memory+leaks).

Comment: What does the React app do?

Comment: It's a note editor using slatejs